# How to append child load first in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append, appendchild

I want add js file dynamically at the first of `<head>` tag. my file is given below

Examble link : [Link](http://demo.osiztechnologies.com/testing.html)

**Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        function load() {
        var doc = document;
        var url = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js";
        var id =  1;
        var script = doc.createElement("script");
        script.type = "text/javascript";
        script.src = url;
        script.id = id;
        //alert(script);
        var head = doc.getElementsByTagName( "head" )[ 0 ].appendChild( script );

        }
         window.onload = load;

        </script>   
<title>Nathan</title>
<style>
table{
    width:200px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:#eee;
    text-align:center;
    cursor:pointer;
}
th{
    background-color:#333;
    color:#FFF;
}
div#lyrics{
    width:200px;
    height:400px;
    background-color:#7C8698;
    position:absolute;
    left:500px;
    padding:10px;

}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("div#lyrics").hide();

    $("#songlist tr").mouseover(function(){
        $(this).css("background-color","#ccc");
        $("#lyrics",this).show();
    }).mouseout(function(){
        $(this).css("background-color","#eee");
        $("#lyrics",this).hide();
    });

});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <table id="songlist">
        <th>Songs</th>
        <tr><td>song1<div id="lyrics">la la la song1</div></td></tr>
        <tr><td>song2<div id="lyrics">doo doo doo song2</div></td></tr>
        <tr><td>song3<div id="lyrics">fee fi fo fum song3</div></td></tr>
        <tr><td>song4<div id="lyrics">hmm hmmm song 4</div></td></tr>
        <tr><td>song5<div id="lyrics">ma ma mi mi song5</div></td></tr>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Dynamic script adding successfully but its adding last of head tag. so my jquery function not working. so please advise me how can i load my dynamic script on first in head tag

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why don't you just add jQuery within `<script/>` tags instead of doing it this way?

Comment: @putvande No i am creating a browser addon so only i need to load jquery file using javascipt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding jQuery first in the head section will still not work, cause the request to the source file will come async, why dont you add jQuery like a normal script tag:

```
<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>
  <script>/*jQuery dependent code*/</script>
  ...
```

If you will/have to use the async loading you will have to wait for the script to be loaded before adding any jQuery dependent code:

```
<script> // Pseudo code: (Take a look at http://www.ejeliot.com/blog/109 for more complex solution)
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.onload = init;
  script.src = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js';
  document.body.appendChild(script);
</script>

<script>
  function init() { /* now jQuery is loaded */ }
</script>
```

Comment: i am creating a browser addon so only i need to load jquery file using javascipt.

Comment: @NathanSrivi And did you see the 2. part?

Answer (score 0):

Use `.insertBefore()` and `.firstChild` instead of `.appendChild()`

Comment: Or there maybe exist a function "prependChild()" but i'm not sure.

Comment: @Virus721 nope, so weird though.

Answer (score 0):

As you have written your code, the content in the second script tag is run before jQuery is loaded. At that time "$" is not defined.

```
window.onload = load;
```

means you put the content in the load function to be run at "onload". But obviously, content in script tags are being run already. The "load" function as defined will not be executed until all scripts in already defined script tags are executed.

And then, of course, there is some time required to actually download the file.

If you must load jQuery asynchronously, you also must put all JavaScript that depends on jQuery in some callback that gets executed only after jQuery is successfully loaded.

Comment: @NULL made an excellent answer showing how to put all jQuery-dependent JavaScript in a callback.